# Issues with Lucene.NET version 3.0.3

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I've been using Lucene.NET v3.0.3 on a project for several of weeks ago, it very good library in addition to FacetedSearch is wonderful; but there are some points to need to say regarding this version, and I wish some tell me the best practice to tackle:

1. It does not support nested documents (relation between documents), [as it does in lucene java latest versions], for example on my domain model i have (Request, Applicant), one Request contains many Applicants. 
   a. In Indexing phase:i indexed one Request for one Applicant per document,in order to search particular information on Request and Applicant as will;  but this makes:

   - redundant request information on different documents,
   - difficult to use faceted search on (Request) on such document
     Anybody can tell me if there any (way, plugin, code) to handle this issues? but not using solar library.
2. How can return unique result (distinct), Is it the only way to return the whole result then implement code to distinct on the result; this makes performance problem on 1 Million document.
3. Any Implementation on extra cache level, example caching a document field (requestID) for fast performance querying.
4. Any news regarding the next Lucene.NET release date?
5. Any implementation on nested query results on different indexing files.

Comment: http://lucenenet.apache.org/community.html

Comment: You should split each question into it is own post as most aren't directly related and you'll have a better chance of having some answered.

Answer (score 0):

If you can map your relationships to hierarchies, you might look at my [Stupid Lucene Tricks: Hierarchies](http://blogs.perl.org/users/mark_leighton_fisher/2019/05/stupid-lucene-tricks-hierarchies.html) (edit: updated link) which talks about using path enumerations to express and search hierarchies in Lucene.